# Ubuntu shell script not working

Tags: shell, ubuntu, cat

With this script I want to append a line of text to the /etc/hosts file. The script seems not to be working. What is wrong?

```
su 
cd /etc
cat /home/rugile/file >> hosts
```

And /home/rugile/file looks like this:

```
127.0.0.1 domain.com
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`su` opens a new shell. You need to feed it the commands.

```
su << EOF
 ...
EOF
```